# omnetpp.ini File Explanation

Tags: ini, omnet++, inet

```
# ping app (host[0] pinged by others)
*.host[0].numPingApps = 0
*.host[*].numPingApps = 2
*.host[*].pingApp[*].destAddr = "host[0]"
**.pingApp[0].startTime = uniform(1s,5s)
**.pingApp[1].startTime = 5s+uniform(1s,5s)
**.pingApp[*].printPing = true
```

The above is a snippet of an `omnetpp.ini` file for initializing simulations (Currently I'm trying to simulate a WSN "Wireless Sensor Network". Hosts represent sensor nodes. I want to know exactly what does these two lines mean:

```
*.host[0].numPingApps = 0
*.host[*].numPingApps = 2
```

Does it mean that `host[0]` does not ping any of the others, and all the other hosts ping `host[0]` twice? Can someone please explain.

What if I want a packet (or `cMessage`) to travel from `host[0]` to `host[n]`? Is there any packages from INET I can use? (like using `pingApp` does the pinging to a certain host)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The meaning of wildcard symbol in `omnetpp.ini` is explained in [OMNeT++ Manual](https://omnetpp.org/doc/omnetpp/manual/usman.html#sec339).

There is a rule that:

> if a parameter name matches several wildcard-patterns, the first
>   matching occurrence is used.

The two lines you are asking means: `host[0]` does not have any `pingApp`, all other hosts have 2 pingApp's.

As far as the second question is concerned: to generate a traffic from one host to another you can use any of `TCPApp`, or `UDPApp`, for example [UDPBasicApp](https://omnetpp.org/doc/inet/api-current/neddoc/index.html?p=inet.applications.udpapp.UDPBasicApp.html).